# Why is my for loop miscalculating output values?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

```
data=xlsread('Temp_kiln_sp2020.xlsx');
time=data(:,1);
temp=data(:,2);


delta_t=[];
for i=length(temp)-1
delta_t(i)=temp(i)-temp(i+1);
end
```

I don't understand why this code will not run properly the outputs of delta_t should be values not equal 0 all I seem to get are zeros which does not add up. So what is the flaw in my code?

Comment: Check the value of `i` inside the loop...

Comment: are there numbers in your spreadsheet? (Or rather, are there numbers in more than 2 columns?) It seems that `length(temp)` is empty.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Friendly tip: you should avoid using [`length`](https://riptutorial.com/matlab/example/27689/using--length--for-multidimensional-arrays).